# Save Calculated Column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

I have a calculated column that calculates the year when a contract needs to be reviewed and this feeds our contract plan for the year. For example contract expiring 5/1/2023 has "2023" in the calculated column titled "Review Year". My problem is when the someone takes action such as extending the contract, the expiration date changes and resets the value in Review year so we lose visibility in what was in scope for the year in 2023. So as in my example, if 5/1/2023 is changed to 5/1/2026, the new Review Year auto calculates to 2026. Is there any way to save the original calculated column to another column? Or is this just something I will have to do manually at the start of each review cycle?

Comment: The Calculated column calculates values based on other columns, so if the columns involved in the calculation change, the Calculated column will change as well. If you want to save the value of the original calculated column you have to save it manually first.